# Does intermediary condition for existence get "carried away" on final result?

Tags: probability-theory, logic

I think this is trivial but I would appreciate external confirmation on this.

Suppose that for some functions $f$ and $g$ I have the following inequalities
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(|X|>t)& \leq \mathbb{P}(|f(X)|^2+C>t) \\
&= \mathbb{P}(|f(X)|>\sqrt{t-C})\\
&\leq g(t-C)
\end{align}
where the domain of definition of $f$ and $g$ is the real line.

My question is the following: is the condition for the existence of the square root in the second inequality (namely that $t\geq C$) get "carried away" on the last inequality. In other words, given the above, does the inequality 
$$\mathbb{P}(X>t)\leq g(t-C) $$
is true only for $t\geq C$ (and not for all $t\geq 0$) ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The thing is, if $t-C<0$, the event $\left[|f(X)|>\sqrt{t-C}\right]$ does not make sense. Since you got it from the square root of the previous event, I suppose the idea would be that this event is the same as $\left[{|f(X)|}^2>t-C\right]$, which for $t-C<0$ is always true. Does $g$ agree with this?

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you mean by "does $g$ agree with this". The last inequality is obtained because I can bound the probability of $\{|f(X)|>\epsilon\}$ by $g(\epsilon)$ for all $\epsilon \geq 0$ due to some assumption I have on the distribution of $f(X)$. Moreover I know that $g$ make sense even if $t-C<0$.

Comment: The equality $\mathbb{P}(|f(X)|^2+C>t) = \mathbb{P}(|f(X)|>\sqrt{t-C})$ makes sense when $t-C \geqslant 0$, so the last inequality should hold in this case assuming your calculations are correct. When $t-C<0$, the equality $\mathbb{P}(|f(X)|^2+C>t) = \mathbb{P}(|f(X)|>\sqrt{t-C})$ does not make sense because the RHS doesn't. In this case, your final inequality could still be valid if $\mathbb{P}(|f(X)|^2+C>t) \leqslant g(t-C)$ when $t-C < 0$ (directly, without having to go through $\mathbb{P}(|f(X)|>\sqrt{t-C})$, which doesn't make sense here).

Comment: I mean, it could still be valid if $\mathbb{P}(|X|>t)\leqslant g(t-C)$ directly.